# has_many association testing with factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, associations, factory-bot

I have a very simple project. It has a basket that has 3 apples.

I made a new project and added some gems. (RSpec and FactoryGirl included)

I ran

```
rails g scaffold basket
rails g scaffold apple basket:references
rake db:migrate
```

Here is the basket model

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples
end
```

Here is the basket factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :basket do
    transient do
      apples_count 3
    end
    after(:create) do |basket, evaluator|
      create_list(:apple, evaluator.apples_count, basket: basket)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the apple model

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
end
```

Here is the apple factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :apple do
    basket
  end
end
```

Here is the basket_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Basket, type: :model do
  it "has 3 apples" do
    basket = FactoryGirl.build(:basket)
    basket.apples.length.should == 3
  end
end
```

As it stands right now the test fails, because basket.apples.length returns 0 instead of 3. Why isn't it returning 3, and how can I make this test pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the issues is that you would be well served to be a little more rigorous

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :basket do
      # basket attributes here
        factory :basket_w_apples do   
          transient do
            apples_count 3
          end
          after(:create) do |basket, evaluator|
            create_list(:apple, evaluator.apples_count, basket: basket)
          end
        end
   end
 end
```

Then your test would be

```
 require 'rails_helper'

 RSpec.describe Basket, type: :model do
   it "has 3 apples" do
     basket = FactoryGirl.create(:basket_w_apples)
     basket.apples.length.should == 3
   end
 end
```

Of course, the callback is after_create, so you need create rather than build

Comment: Out of curiosity does this change the apple factory at all?
should I replace basket with basket_w_apples?

Comment: No your apple factory was ok. IMO, you should have both :basket and :basket_w_apples factory, since you probably want to test both the core model and its associations.

Answer (score 1):

Your apples are created only when basket is *created*. `#build` doesn't create record (it's analog of ActiveRecord's `#new`, it just initializes without commit).

```
RSpec.describe Basket, type: :model do
  it "has 3 apples" do
    basket = FactoryGirl.create(:basket)
    basket.apples.length.should == 3
  end
end
```

That one should pass.